# Open files selected in Explorer in single Irfanview instance?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

When selecting multiple files in Explorer from a Folder view or search results and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the Windows 10 Photos App and the older Windows Photo Viewer both open the selected files in the same instance and navigation buttons browse within that list of files rather than the directory the files are in.

With Irfanview, when selecting multiple files and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

- If *Settings > Start/Exit Options > Only 1 instance of IrfanView is active* is enabled, the files will all open but all but the last just close. For that one image, browsing browses in its directory, not in the list of selected files.
- If the setting is not enabled, each file is opened in a separate instance, in browsing browses in its directory.

This is particularly curious, because when running IrfanView from the command line, invoking it as `i_view64 FILE1.jpg FILE2.jpg ...` will browser the given list of files, as seem with the stock apps.

Is it possible to configure IrfanView such that the same behavior is seen when opening multiple files from Explorer?

### Workaround

Adding "IrfanView" to the "SendTo" folder has the desired behavior, but inferior integration compared to the stock apps.

Method:

1. In the start menu, right click type IrfanView
2. Right click IrfanView program and select "Open file location"
3. In a separate Explorer window, go to `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo`.
4. Copy the IrfanView link to "SendTo".
5. In order to assign the entry a hotkey, rename the Link in SendTo such that it contains `&<some letter>`, e.g. as `Irfan&View` or `IrfanView (&v)`.